# jquery change background color to hex value

Tags: css, jquery, background-color

I have a table with cell ids of "quest_row1", "quest_row2", etc. I want to change the background color of a cell to a hex value that I am returning via AJAX call to server.

```
picked_answer = $(this).val();
    x = parseInt($("input#q_num").val());
    $.post("CCRN/submit_answer.php", {num : x, answer:picked_answer}, function(data) 
        {
            alert(data+x);
            $("#quest_row" + x).css({'background-color' : '#' + data});
        });
```

x gets the correct value, say 10. data is returned from AJAX call is correct, say AABBCC. The color does not change but I get no errors. This code does run as the alert box shows the correct values for the data and x. Please help identify my issue!

Comment: Could you check whether the selector is actually selecting elements? I mean, insert the line `alert($('#quest_row'+x).length)` and tell me what is displayed in the pop-up window: it should display `1`.

Comment: It does indeed return the value 1 in the alert box.

Comment: Is `quest_row`a `<tr>`element?

Comment: I just tried putting an actual hex value instead of data variable in the selector css statement and it works. But I KNOW I am returning a string that can be a hex color. Do I need to force type the data variable into a hex or string?

Comment: So you did `$("#quest_row" + x).css({'background-color' : '#AABBCC'});` and it works, doesn't it?

Comment: @HenryGeiter do this: `alert(data.split("").map(function(v){return v.charCodeAt(0);}).join(" ") )`. If the server is not strictly sending a 6 character hex color, this will show it.

Comment: tried the alert data.split and it threw and error saying method not supported on object. and @Cludix, the code with actual hex value works, but I won't know the hex value except as return from callback function

Comment: that is interesting, just one curious [question](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), what does this shows: `alert(typeof data);` or `alert(data.toSource());` ?

Answer (score 0):

First check if the css style is added to the element via firebug or what ever console your using. In firebug when you inspect it, it should show as element.style{...}

It may also be that your adding it to the tr which might not work as i know styling tables does not always work as expected. Try adding the style to the td instead and see if this helps.

Comment: It is on the td element and it works with hardcoded hex color value, just not the AABBCC returned from the AJAX call.

Comment: It could be that you have more than one ID with the same name. So it's picking up an array of elements instead of a single one. Try looping through it with $.each.